# deserialize data on the fly from stream or file

Tags: c++, serialization

It is more or less quite easy to serialize and deserialze data structures with common libraries like boost::serialize.

But there is an also common case where I simply do something like ( pseudo code ):

```
// receiver
NetworkInputStreamSerialzer stream;

while (1) // read new data objects from stream
{
    stream & data;
}
```

As I expect the data package must already be received complete from the network socket. If only a part of the object can be read the deserialization will fail. Especially with large data sets TCP will fragment the data.

Is there a generic way to deal with this problem? I have not found any hints to this problem in the docs from boost::serialize.

As this problem is generic to any kind of streamed data, not only for TCP based streaming but also for files where one prog sends and another receives the data, there must be a general solution but I could not find anything about.

My question is not specialized to boost. I use it only as an example.

EDIT:
Maybe some more explanation to my wording of "fragmentation":

Any kind of data, independent of the size it produces in serialized format, can be fragmented in several packages while transferred via TCP or by writing it to any kind of file. There is no kind of "atomic" write and read operation which is supported from the OS neither the serialization libraries I know.

So if reading an int from a human readable format like XML or JSON I can get the problem that I read a "11" instead of "112" if the "2" is not in the stream or file in the moment I read from it. So writing the length of the following content in a human readable format is also not a solution, because the size information itself can be corrupt while the read occurs in the moment the content string is not complete in this moment.

Comment: See this: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/iostreams/http_client.cpp

Comment: why not split up your large data unit into smaller data units that can be processed separately ?

Comment: @SanderDeDycker: Fragmentation can also occur if a huge amount of small data sets are generated. It should work in general.

Comment: the problem is to know - while deserializing your large data unit - when you are at a point where some of the deserialized data is available for use, and specifically what deserialized data is available. If instead you split up the data unit into smaller data units which can be separately deserialized, you know exactly when data is available (after a small data unit is fully received and deserialized), and what data is available (the data related to that small data unit). I'm not sure what you mean by fragmentation. You'd be sending the same data in the same order, just with explicit splits.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker I tried to clarify my question a bit. See update. `if instead you split up the data unit into smaller data units` will not help, because there is no size which is guaranteed to be transferred atomic. OK, splitting down to a single byte will help :-)

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood your question. I thought you *wanted* to be able to deserialize a partial data unit. But you just want it to wait until all is received before attempting to deserialize. You have two options : Add size information at the start of the stream, then read the right amount of bytes from the stream, and deserialize when all is received. Or add error handling to a failed deserialization to wait and try again.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>[Note: I get a sense from your Q, that you want a better alternative for `boost::serialization` for your specific case. If this doesn't answer your Q, then let me know, I shall delete it.]</sub>

Recommending to use [Google Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) from my own practical experience. Below are few advantages:

1. It can be used on wire (TCP etc.)
2. Simple grammar to write the .proto file for composing your own
   messages
3. Cross platform & available with multiple languages
4. Very efficient compared to JSON & XML
5. Generates header & source files for handy getter, setter, serialize,
   deserialize & debugging purpose
6. Easy to serialize & deserialize -- store to & retrieve from file

The last point is bit tricky. While storing in a file, you may have to insert the length of the message first and while retrieving, you may have to first read that length & then use `read()` method to read the exact number of bytes.

Above same trick you may want to use while passing on TCP. In first couple of bytes, the length can be passed. Once the length is determined, you can always collect the remaining fragmented message.

Comment: "you may have to insert the length of the message first and while retrieving, " Q: Is it guaranteed that the length information can always be read complete ( atomic ) from the file? Maybe exactly that information is written over the block boundary of the file and data becomes available while first block from disk can be read but the last byte of the size information is stored in the next block?

Comment: @Klaus, I am not sure about the atomicity of the length information of the file. In all practical scenarios, it works well. However, it's a good point.